# Sans montrer (ni / d') effroi ni colère

Tags: négation, conjonctions

> Il demeure immobile, sans montrer **ni** effroi **ni** colère.
>
> Il demeure immobile, sans montrer **d**'effroi **ni** colère.
>
> Il demeure immobile, sans montrer effroi **ni** colère.

Je pense que les deux premières phrases sont correctes, et la troisième non. Mais, à mon avis, c'est la troisième phrase qui devrait être correcte en raison de *sans*. Est-ce que celle-ci est quand même acceptable ?

Answer (score 2):

Il demeure immobile, sans montrer ni effroi ni colère.✅

Il demeure immobile, sans montrer d'effroi ni colère.❌ sans montrer d’effroi ni de colère

Il demeure immobile, sans montrer effroi ni colère.❌ sans montrer ni effroi ni colère

On n’utilise pas ni devant le premier complément d’objet direct s’il est introduit par de, déterminant.

Comment: Merci ! Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre les phrases _sans montrer ni effroi ni colère_ et _sans montrer d’effroi ni de colère_, est-ce que leur sens est un peu différent ?

Comment: Je pense qu’il y a une petite nuance. Sans le déterminant, c’est plutôt qualitatif, on fait plutôt référence à la notion. Avec le déterminant, c’est plutôt quantitatif, et comme la phrase est négative, la « quantité » est nulle : on pourrait dire « sans un soupçon de colère ou d’effroi ». 

Je pense que cette nuance peut être fait en anglais : without anger / without any anger.

Comment: Oui, merci, je comprends mieux. Comment avez-vous fait pour modifier votre commentaire ? Si j'écris le mien et que 3 ou 5 minutes passent, je ne peux plus l'éditer.

Comment: On ne peut pas le modifier après 5 minutes. Je le copie, je supprime le message et j’en fait un nouveau.